# Android App development without Eclipse/ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'd like to learn Android app development but I don't want to use any IDE, especially Eclipse and its ADT plug in. It's just that I'm more comfortable with command line, executing commands myself and seeing what's going on beneath. I'm looking for a good reference/tutorial/ebook/walk through on the flow. Is there any such resources available?

Answer (score 4):

From the android dev. website:  http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Ofcourse the title suggests using a different IDE, but it explains what directories you need, how to compile your .APK etc.

Ofcourse, you need de SDK and the tools from there, but that's a given. You can however use the above information to develop without Eclipse/ADT

Comment: link is dead, please provide proper link

Comment: I just did (quick google search for that title wasn't all that hard). A complete answer would be better, but it's a long writedown. (basically the answer is more "read the manual" :)  )